# How to get status from FB like button added to my own web page?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've added a Facebook Like button to a web page on my own server, like this:

```
<div class="fb-like"></div>
```

I want to display some info for those who liked this page, and I can do this by subscribing to edge.create event:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function() { /*Show info...*/ });
```

I also need to make the info visible as long as like status remain active when he/she re-entered this page. I knew the button can check the status itself (so it can show correct image and styles), but how to get the status for my own use?

Comment: “Like Gating” is not allowed any more by Facebook. You are not allowed to show content only to people who liked your page, and keep it from others.

Answer (score 0):

That´s only possible in a serious way by authorizing a user with the `user_likes` permission and using the `/me/likes` endpoint. You can also store the info in a cookie, but there is no way to detect if a user already liked it if he clears his cookies.

Btw, incentivizing likes is not allowed, so if you want to show additional information that is only visible to users who liked it: that´s not allowed according to the [platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/).

Comment: `/me/likes` can only be used to look up fan pages the user liked, normal web site pages is not listed.

Comment: that is correct. if you want to like the website directly, then there is no way to seriously find out.